# Overriding AutoFac scoping configuration when using factory

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

How to configure AutoFac so that I get a new instance of `Context` every time I hit the factory.  The `Content` component is set to `InstancePerLifetimeScope()`, which is perfect for 99% of my usage, but now I need a little extra control over how the `Context` component is scoped.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterType<Box>();
        builder.RegisterType<DbContext>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        var container = builder.Build();

        using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {
            var x = scope.Resolve<Box>();
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

class Box
{
    public Box(DbContext.Factory factory)
    {
        factory();
        factory(); // Want this to generate a NEW instance

        Console.WriteLine("Box: {0}", GetHashCode());
    }
}

class DbContext
{
    public delegate DbContext Factory();

    public DbContext()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Context: {0}", GetHashCode());
    }
}
```

Obviously, this is a rather simplified snippet of code.  The problem I am trying to solve is that I have a huge stream of data coming into a service and I am trying to batch-save to the database.  So, if `Box` can create new UOWs on demand, and release them back for disposal in a timely fashion, then I get a nice clean solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Func<Owned<>>` which works like a small `ILifetimeScope` :

```
public Box(Func<Owned<DbContext>> factory)
{
    using (Owned<DbContext> ownedDbContext = factory())
    {
        // instance1
    }
    using (Owned<DbContext> ownedDbContext = factory())
    {
        // instance2 
    }
}
```

You can find more details on the Autofac documentation : [Owned Instances](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/owned-instances.html)

Another solution is to inject `ILifetimeScope` and then create a sub lifetimescope :

```
public Box(ILifetimeScope scope)
{
    using (ILifetimeScope subScope = scope.BeginLifetimeScope())
    {
        DbContext dbContext = subScope.Resolve<DbContext>();
    }
}
```

or

```
public Box(ILifetimeScope scope)
{
    ILifetimeScope subScope = scope.BeginLifetimeScope();
    scope.Disposer.AddInstanceForDisposal(subScope);
    DbContext dbContext = subScope.Resolve<DbContext>(); 
    // no need to dispose subScope, 
    // subScope (and dbContext) will be disposed at the same time as scope
}
```

Comment: Yep.  I have come to the same solution.  Nice one.

Comment: OwnedInstances doesn't work if type is registred as InstancePerRequest. I get the same instance. Any suggestions?

Comment: sue instanceperLifeTimeScope if you want per each scope